# How to find title and list where data-id is highest number

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I want to click the element with highest data-id. I'm generating title like this:

```
char_set = string.ascii_uppercase
    tagTitle = "AI TAG " + ''.join(random.sample(char_set * 4, 4))
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='FolderName']").send_keys(tagTitle)
```

Currently I'm getting all elements of UI class:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/ul/li")
```

[image]

```html
<ul class="investorGroup ul-groups">
   <li data-id="-1" class="">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="$.InvestorContact.Group.LoadGroupInvestorsOnGroupClick(-1,null, 0)">Master</a>
   </li>
   <li title="AI TAG AOAI" data-id="371">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="$.InvestorContact.Group.LoadGroupInvestorsOnGroupClick(371)">2451b 24 (<span class="contactCatCount">0</span>)</a>
      <a href="javascript:$.InvestorContact.Group.OpenAddGroupModal(371)" class="edit"><i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
   </li>
   <li title="AI TAG CANG" data-id="376" >
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="$.InvestorContact.Group.LoadGroupInvestorsOnGroupClick(376)">452352 (<span class="contactCatCount">0</span>)</a>
      <a href="javascript:$.InvestorContact.Group.OpenAddGroupModal(376)" class="edit"><i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

now tried and its showing the element :

> $x('/html/body/div[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dksoz.png)/div[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dksoz.png)/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NgNWN.png)/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NgNWN.png)/div/div[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dksoz.png)/ul/li[contains(@title,"AI
>   TAG FOVE")]')

[image]
but does not click and gives error via python:

> TagElement =
>   driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dksoz.png)/div[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dksoz.png)/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NgNWN.png)/div[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NgNWN.png)/div/div[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dksoz.png)/ul/li[contains(@title,"AI
>   TAG FOVE")]')
>           TagElement.click()

sorry if i skip something just a learner here.

> selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element ... is not clickable at point (122, 388). Other element would receive the click: ...
>     (Session info: chrome=80.0.3987.132)

Comment: tried following as well: $x('/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/ul/li[contains(@title," AI TAG AOAI")]')

Answer (score 1):

First you can get all the elements in a list and then you can click on the last element because that would be having the highest `data-id` and if you want to get the title which you are clicking then you can get it by using `get_attribute()` method.

You can do it like:

```
# Fetching the elements using xpath
title_list = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//ul[@class='investorGroup ul-groups']//li[contains(@title,'AI TAG')]")  

# Getting the title of the last element
title_list[-1].get_attribute("title")   

# Clicking on the last element
title_list[-1].click()
```

**Edited ans for picking text from a variable:**

```
value = "AI TAG"
```

Now fetch the list by using:

```
title_list = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//ul[@class='investorGroup ul-groups']//li[contains(@title,"+value+")]")
```

Comment: now its clicking just need to update its driver.find_elements_by_xpath else i got TypeError.
Thanks for the help

Comment: @zarmehdi yes i made a mistake there, have updated my answer.

Comment: and can i replace this static title with my variable?
title_list = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//ul[@class='investorGroup ul-groups']//li[contains(@title,(tagTitle))]")

Comment: @zarmehdi yes you can do it, you can first assign a value into a string and then use that string in the xpath.

Comment: im using tagTitle variable to generate the title
updated my variable as:
tagTitle = str("AI TAG " + ''.join(random.sample(char_set * 4, 4)))
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='FolderName']").send_keys(tagTitle)

now using tagTitle as following:
title_list = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//ul[@class='investorGroup ul-groups']//li[contains(@title,"+tagTitle+")]")

SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//ul[@class='investorGroup ul-groups']//li[contains(@title,AI TAG NQVH)]' is not a valid XPath expression.

Answer (score 1):

First get all the `<li>` tag in a list present under particular `<ul>`. Iterate through the loop and get compare and store highest `data-id` attribute value element. Finally click on that highest value element.

Use below code :

```
list_of_li = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.investorGroup.ul-groups li')

container = 0
number = None
for element in list_of_li:
    number = element.get_attribute('data-id')

    if container < int(number):
        container = int(number)
        max_element = element

print(container)

max_element.click()
```

Comment: Local variable 'number' might be referenced before assignment this is what IDe is showing!

Comment: @zarmehdi `is a warning generated by the linter` apart from this is it functioning as you expected ?

Comment: @zarmehdi, code updated `To get rid of this warning, you can simply initialize the variable before any of the if conditions with None value`

Comment: selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=80.0.3987.132)

Comment: At which line ? seems your page getting reload after performing click somewhere

Comment: yeah because before this the page generates the above tag and save
after reloads i want to open the tag i created which has this highest data-id

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209559/discussion-between-narendrar-and-zarmehdi).